# Sending signal to systemd to stop messages from appearing on console

Tags: systemd, logs, console, signals

systemd's man-page https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html says that one can send `SIGRTMIN+21` to the systemd process to disable status message such as `Started Login service.` etc. from appearing on the console. The relevant snippet from man page is below:

```
SIGRTMIN+21
Disables display of status messages on the console, as controlled via 
systemd.show_status=0 on the kernel command line.
```

When I look at the process table, there are at least 4 different processes associated with systemd. Which of these is referred to in the man-page?

```
~# ps -ef |grep [s]ystemd
root       448     1  0 18:47 ?        00:00:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       450     1  0 18:47 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root       722     1  0 18:47 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/cgmanager -m name=systemd
root       723     1  0 18:47 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
message+   742     1  0 18:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

I wrote a simple daemon that does nothing other than sleeping for 10 secs continuing and ensured that it starts upon boot.

I took a wild guess and sent the signal to `cgmanager` process (pid `722`) as:

```
# kill -SIGRTMIN+21 722
```

There were a couple of messages on the console about restarting the Cgroup daemon, but the "Start job ...." message continues to appear on the console:

```
[  OK  ] Stopped Cgroup management daemon.
[  OK  ] Started Cgroup management daemon.

Server lin1 ttyS0

[   ***] A start job is running for Sleep te... initialization (51s / no lim
```

Has anyone been able to disable console logging like I attempted to do above? If so how?

Comment: is it only journald doing any logging? I just ask, because in Debian rsyslog can at least log some things to the console.

Comment: `dmesg -n 1` might be another way to limit console spam.

Comment: `dmesg -n 1` doesn't work either :(

Comment: Appended `systemd.show_status=0` to kernel command line and no systemd messages appeared on the console! I wish sending a signal to systemd would also give the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running systemd as your init system, the process that you need to send those signals to is the one with PID 1 (it might be called `init` on your system instead of `systemd`).

I don't think the process logs anything upon receiving SIGRTMIN+21, but it does upon receiving SIGUSR1 (which causes systemd to reconnect to the D-Bus bus):

```
kill -SIGUSR1 1
```

`journalctl -e` will then show:

```
Dez 30 20:34:25 mineo-foobar systemd[1]: Trying to reconnect to bus...
```

The above only shows that PID 1 is the correct one to send the signals to, but to stop the status messages, you still have to use `kill -SIGRTMIN+21 1`.

Comment: Does the man-page say that the signal should be sent to `init` instead? I sent `SIGUSR1` to `init` but that didn't help. The service continues to hog my console with the same message as before.

Comment: `# ls -l /sbin/init 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Aug 27  2015 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd` Sending `kill -SIGRTMIN+21 1` does indeed stop the spam. @Wieland - I'll accept your answer if you edit it accordingly. thanks